# Trigger to fire after some minutes

Tags: trigger

How to fire a trigger after 20minutes of Lead creation?

- Should check a condition in 20 minutes after the lead is created

Comment: [Time Based Workflows](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245).

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [Time Based Workflows](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005245). Note, however, that you can only schedule them some number of hours or days away from the trigger date. The most obvious workaround, then, would be to include a `Workflow Field Update` in the same rule and update a custom `Datetime` field with the value `NOW() + 20 / (24 * 60)`. Then you can fire the time trigger 0 hours before this custom field.

Comment: Process Builder time based actions have the same restriction of needing to be a number of hours or days from the triggering date/time and hours will only work correctly with Datetime fields.

Comment: Adrian, can you please elaborate because its not working.